# Как перевести сайт с помощью cookies?

Tags: php, cookie

Планируем переводить сайт на англ. версию. 
Есть несколько вопросов для тех, у кого уже был такой опыт.

Самым оптимальным и менее затратным я считаю на cookies. 
Создадим cookie -> язык.

Далее подходим к проблеме. Она заключается в ajax запросах, потому что у нас их очень много. Я думаю, что нужно создать директорию для русских и английских запросов. Является ли правильным такой подход? Или можно как-то проще сделать?

Также с текстами не знаю, как сделать. Постоянно cookie проверять?

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться компонентом от симфони, для мультиязычного сайта https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation.html

Comment: Ваш проект написан с использованием каких-нибудь фреймворков? Какая у него структура?

Comment: Самописный на PHP